# Error when running Visual Studio project on Raspiberry Pi 2 with Windows IoT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi, visual-studio, windows-iot-core

I am currently trying to deploy a UWP project to my raspberry pi to see if it works properly, but I cannot even get it to run. Whenever I build and deploy, I get the error `DEP0100: Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled. Could not obtain a developer license on 192.168.x.xxx due to error 80004005.`

I already have enabled developer mode on my development PC, which is what seems to be the only recommendation I've found online. My Pi is detected when I go to select where to run the Debug, as it auto detects the IP address of the pi.

Comment: I assume you have developer mode enabled on both machines?  If you don't have Developer Mode on both machines, then that is the source, of this particular error.

Comment: @Ramhound I have it enabled on my PC, and I assume it is on my PI as well. Otherwise, I don't know how to enable it on the PI and I cannot find how

Comment: [Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324300/ensure-that-target-device-has-developer-mode-enabled-could-not-obtain-a-develop)

Comment: @Ramhound this does not solve my issue, my device is already indeveloper mode